# Packing an array and only process when full

Tags: c, arrays

I'm working on an embedded c app. The app downloads a file and writes to flash memory. The requirements are that I can only write to flash in blocks of 64 bytes (1 page).  THe binary firmware file gets downloaded in chunks no bigger than 64 bytes (e.g. 64 or less bytes). However I am getting the data is different lengths. For example:

1st packet size :62 bytes

2nd packet size :64

3rd packet size :64

4th packet size :64

5th packet size :43

6th packet size :64

....

last packet: length: 7

**I need to keep track of the bytes, pack the bytes into a buffer until its full (64 bytes) then write to flash.**

I am having a heck a time figuring this out. Here is what I have so far, but is not right and my `rmdBuff` gets thrown off. I am looking for some guidance.

**Global vars**

```
uint8_t temp[64]; // buffer to send when full           
uint8_t rmdBuff[64]; // buffer to pack
uint8_t temp_indx; 
uint8_t rmd_indx;
uint8_t buffer_room_needed; // keep track of how much room in rmdBuff
uint8_t rem_offset; 
uint16_t bit_ct; // how many bits processed
uint16_t rowct; // for debugging
```

Function

```
void store_file_packet(char *data, uint32_t length)
{       
    if ((data == NULL) || (length < 1)) {           
        return;
    }

    if (!is_state_set(DOWNLOADING)) {

        printf("********* Initial Start of Download **************\n\r");

        received_file_size = 0;
        add_state(DOWNLOADING);

        temp_indx = 0;
        rmd_indx = 0;
        buffer_room_needed = 0;
        rem_offset = 0;
        bit_ct = 0;
        rowct = 1;  

    }

    if (data != NULL) {     

        memset(temp, 0, sizeof temp); // clear temp 

        if(rmd_indx > 0){       
            // figure out how much room we have in rmd array
            buffer_room_needed = 64 - rmd_indx; 

            rem_offset = abs(length - buffer_room_needed);  

            memcpy(&rmdBuff[rmd_indx],&data[0],buffer_room_needed); // only copy over what we have room for         

            rmd_indx = rmd_indx + buffer_room_needed;   

            if(rmd_indx > 63){ // rmd buffer is full

                memcpy(temp,&rmdBuff,64); // copy over all 64 bytes             
                memset(rmdBuff, 0, sizeof rmdBuff); // clear rmdBuff                    
                temp_indx = 63;// full      
                rmd_indx = 0;

                // add anything else to rmdBuff?
                memcpy(&rmdBuff[rmd_indx],&data[buffer_room_needed + 1],rem_offset);    
                rmd_indx += rem_offset;         
            }

        } else {

            if(length != 64){               
                // not enough, copy over to hold array              
                memcpy(rmdBuff,&data[0],length); 
                rmd_indx += length;

            } else {
                memcpy(temp,&data[0],length); // copy over all 64 bytes 
                temp_indx = 63; // full 

            }           
        }

        if(temp_indx == 63){
            // write temp buffer to memory
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just use a 128-byte ringbuffer?

Comment: @EOF can you elaborate? I considered a ring buffer, but wasnt sure if it would work

Comment: A 128 byte ringbuffer guarantees that a 64-byte maximum write to the buffer will not overflow as long as less than 64 bytes are currently in the buffer. Also, your current code already uses two 64-byte buffers, so the ringbuffer is no worse in size. Depending on your platform, you may have DMA modes for ringbuffers, potentially with half-transfer interrupt, which would seem ideally suited for this task.